Flutter: Make Australian locale fall back to British localization
I have a Flutter app with an app_en.arb file providing US English localization:
{
    "@@locale": "en",
    "someMessage": "Pick a color.",
    "@someMessage": {
        "description": "Just some arbitrary message"
    }
}

It's also got an app_en_GB.arb file for the British version of the language:
{
    "@@locale": "en_GB",
    "someMessage": "Pick a colour."
}

If I, for testing purposes, set my app to explicitly use a British locale…
const MaterialApp(
  home: MyHomeWidget(),
  locale: Locale("en", "GB"),
  localizationsDelegates: AppLocalizations.localizationsDelegates,
  supportedLocales: AppLocalizations.supportedLocales,
)

…, it picks up the appropriate language variant. However, for an Australian locale…
const MaterialApp(
  home: MyHomeWidget(),
  locale: Locale("en", "AU"),
  localizationsDelegates: AppLocalizations.localizationsDelegates,
  supportedLocales: AppLocalizations.supportedLocales,
)

…, the default app_en.arb file is employed.
I tried renaming the app_en.arb file to app_en_US.arb, but that's giving me an error:
Generating synthetic localizations package failed with 1 error:

Error: The 'template-arb-file', LocalFile: '[…]/lib/l10n/app_en.arb', does not exist.

Of course, one could provide a custom localeResolutionCallback, as described here, to handle this scenario, but that seems like a bit of a hassle.
Since eight of the nine English locales supported by Flutter represent language variants closer to British English, would it not make sense to go one step further and use British English in the default app_en.arb file, then provide an app_en_US.arb file for the US variant?
But what about non-English locales? What if I would like them to fall back to US English (one may argue about that of course)?
How do you handle this?
